# 2 baseboard connection

Tags: wiring

I have 2 baseboard, one old model with integrated thermostat and a new model with integrated thermostat.
I want to install a Junction Box 1 source in 2, to connect the 2 baseboards, I uploaded an image. I want you guys to tell me if my connection is ok.[image]

Comment: How many watts do those basement units take? What gauge wire and circuit breaker will be feeding them? I strongly suspect this would be beyond what your existing installed wiring can handle.